# How do I plot three variables using the same time variable? geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been searching for a while to try to solve my problem myself but haven't come across anything that seems to work with my data. I have this dataframe:

```
    dput(mydata2)
structure(list(Sample = structure(c(44L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 
26L, 32L, 40L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 18L, 16L, 27L, 33L, 41L, 8L, 6L, 
12L, 19L, 17L, 28L, 34L, 42L, 29L, 35L, 43L, 30L, 36L, 45L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 31L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
46L, 47L), .Label = c("10242016 Female 2D", "10242016 Female 2D 10 minutes", 
"10242016 Female 2D 100 Refs", "10242016 Female 2D 100 Refs 10 minutes", 
"10242016 Female 2D 100 Refs 20 minutes", "10242016 Female 2D 100 Refs 30 minutes", 
"10242016 Female 2D 20 minutes", "10242016 Female 2D 30 minutes", 
"10242016 Female 2D 500 Refs", "10242016 Female 2D 500 Refs 10 minutes", 
"10242016 Female 2D 500 Refs 20 minutes", "10242016 Female 2D 500 Refs 30 minutes", 
"11012016 Female 2D", "11012016 Female 2D 10 minutes", "11012016 Female 2D 100 Refs 10 minutes", 
"11012016 Female 2D 100 Refs 20 minutes", "11012016 Female 2D 100 Refs 30 minutes", 
"11012016 Female 2D 20 minutes", "11012016 Female 2D 30 minutes", 
"11072016 Female 2D", "11102016 Female 2D", "11142016 Male 2D", 
"11172016 Male 2D", "11212016 Male 2D", "12072016 Male 1D", "12072016 Male 1D 10 Minutes", 
"12072016 Male 1D 20 Minutes", "12072016 Male 1D 30 Minutes", 
"12072016 Male 1D 40 Minutes", "12072016 Male 1D 50 Minutes", 
"12092016 Male 1D", "12092016 Male 1D 10 minutes", "12092016 Male 1D 20 minutes", 
"12092016 Male 1D 30 minutes", "12092016 Male 1D 40 minutes", 
"12092016 Male 1D 50 minutes", "12122016 Male 1D", "12162016 Male 1D", 
"12212016 Female 1D", "12212016 Female 1D 10 Minutes", "12212016 Female 1D 20 Minutes", 
"12212016 Female 1D 30 Minutes", "12212016 Female 1D 40 Minutes", 
"12212016 Female 1D 5 Minutes", "12212016 Female 1D 50 Minutes", 
"12232016 Female 1D", "12282016 Female 1D"), class = "factor"), 
    Minutes_to_100 = c(NA, 9.11666666666667, 9.1, 9.1, 8.86666666666667, 
    8.86666666666667, NA, NA, NA, 9.11666666666667, 9.1, 9.1, 
    8.86666666666667, 8.86666666666667, NA, NA, 15.0333333333333, 
    9.03333333333333, 9.01666666666667, 9.01666666666667, 8.86666666666667, 
    8.86666666666667, NA, NA, 15.0333333333333, NA, NA, 15.0333333333333, 
    NA, NA, 15.0333333333333, 9.03333333333333, 9.1, 9.1, 7.63333333333333, 
    10.3, 9.18333333333333, 11.2166666666667, 15.4333333333333, 
    12.45, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.25, 26.3, 16.4833333333333), runtime = c(4.6, 
    6.3, 3.5, 4.5, 11.3, 8.1, 0.9, 0.8, 4.9, 6.5, 3.5, 4.5, 11.1, 
    8.1, 0.9, 0.9, 4.3, 6.3, 3.2, 4.5, 11.3, 8.3, 1.1, 1, 4.3, 
    1, 1, 4.3, 1.1, 1.1, 4.6, 7.5, 4.2, 4.3, 11.5, 15, 6.8, 15.5, 
    30.7, 34, 6, 16.1, 7.2, 8.9, 6.5, 2.5, 5.2), Sample_type = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("1D", "2D"), class = "factor"), Analysis_min = c(5, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 
    60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
    60)), .Names = c("Sample", "Minutes_to_100", "runtime", "Sample_type", 
"Analysis_min"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -47L
))
```

I want to create a plot using ggplot2 that will show both runtime and Minutes_to_100, probably jittered, using the same Analysis_min variable.

Here is the plot with just Analysis_min vs runtime:

```
ggplot(mydata2, aes(Analysis_min, runtime))+geom_point(aes(color = factor(Sample_type)))
```

[image]

And here is the plot with Analysis_min vs Minutes_to_100:

```
ggplot(mydata2, aes(Analysis_min, Minutes_to_100))+geom_point(aes(color = factor(Sample_type)))
```

[image]

I am not seeing how to combine both variables in one plot.  What I think I want is one plot with Analysis_min on the x-axis, runtime on the Y-axis, and the points for Minutes_to_100 included on the plot.

Comment: I am not sure which answer to mark as the accepted answer.  I ended up combining both suggestions as both provided different parts that I used in my plot.

Comment: [This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-do-i-combine-two-answers-to-create-the-best-answer-on-stackoverflow) suggests you create a new answer from the two provided ones and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to `gather` your data into a new object that contains a column that can take on either `Minutes_to_100` or `runtime`. You could then `colour` by this variable and `shape` by the `Sample_type`.

```
#libraries
    library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)

#gather data
df <- mydata2 %>%
  gather(var, val, -Sample, -Sample_type, -Sample_type, -Analysis_min, )

> head(df)
                                  Sample Sample_type Analysis_min            var      val
1           12212016 Female 1D 5 Minutes          1D            5 Minutes_to_100       NA
2          10242016 Female 2D 10 minutes          2D           10 Minutes_to_100 9.116667
3 10242016 Female 2D 100 Refs 10 minutes          2D           10 Minutes_to_100 9.100000
4 10242016 Female 2D 500 Refs 10 minutes          2D           10 Minutes_to_100 9.100000
5          11012016 Female 2D 10 minutes          2D           10 Minutes_to_100 8.866667
6 11012016 Female 2D 100 Refs 10 minutes          2D           10 Minutes_to_100 8.866667   


ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = Analysis_min, y = val, 
           colour = var, shape = Sample_type)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

As you note, a `jitter` might be helpful.

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = Analysis_min, y = val, 
           colour = var, shape = Sample_type)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could map the value of Minutes_to_100 to colour, then use a shape aesthetic for sample_type.

```
ggplot(mydata2, 
       aes(x = Analysis_min, 
           y = runtime, 
           colour = Minutes_to_100, 
           shape = factor(Sample_type))) + 
  geom_point()
```

Or you could facet by Sample_type:

```
   ggplot(mydata2, 
       aes(x = Analysis_min, 
           y = runtime, 
           colour = Minutes_to_100)) + 
   geom_point() +
   facet_wrap(~Sample_type)
```